# Are there any classes or prestige classes in Pathfinder 1e that alter or change the characters base type permanently?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, races

In Dungeons & Dragons 3.X, there are a number of classes and prestige classes, like Dragon Disciple, and Green Star Adept, that permanently alters the characters base type... I was wondering if there were any others than Dragon Disciple in Pathfinder 1e as I'm not as familiar with it as I am 3.X.

For example, in Pathfinder, could you permanently turn yourself into an Outsider, or Construct, or Fey, for example, as part of a class or prestige class in Pathfinder, other than Dragon Disciple?

Comment: 3.5e’s dragon disciple and green star adept changed your *type*, but not your *race*. If you were a human dragon disciple, you were still human, could still take human racial options, you just were a Dragon and not a Humanoid. On the other hand, 3.5e **did** have a few options that actually changed (well, truthfully, added to) your *race*, such as renegade mastermaker and (less so) stoneblessed (that was more of a “counts as” situation). Which of these two things are you asking about?

Comment: @KRyan You are, as always, correct in your discerning my meaning and the technicality of the rules.

Comment: Uh, that was an either-or question; I don’t know which of the two you mean. I suggest you edit the question to either say “type” instead of “race,” or to change your examples to renegade mastermaker.

Answer (score 9):

No class really changes your *race*, but some change your creature *type*.

Usually such creature type changes are capstone abilities (i.e. gained at level 20), like the [Monk](https://www.aonprd.com/ClassDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Monk)'s / [Unchained Monk](https://www.aonprd.com/ClassDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Monk%20(Unchained))'s *Perfect Self*, turning the character into an Outsider. There are several such capstones, sometimes as such plain class features, sometimes with specific class paths and sometimes as an archetype feature (e.g. [Planar Oracles](https://www.aonprd.com/ArchetypeDisplay.aspx?FixedName=Oracle%20Planar%20Oracle)).

Some creature types are more common – like the Outsider – while others are very rare, like the [Nature Oracle](https://www.aonprd.com/MysteryDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Nature)'s ability to turn into an Animal or Plant creature.

Changing your race is still possible, though usually with spells like [Reincarnate](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Reincarnate), instead of with class abilities.

Humanoids are also considered to be of a specific race, if they have a racial subtype, so acquiring such a subtype would add a race to your character:

> [Advanced Race Guide](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Humanoid%20(0%20RP)&Category=Type%20Quality):
>
> If a humanoid has a racial subtype, it is considered a member of that
> race in the case of race prerequisites.

For example, a humanoid Sorcerer, who has the [Orc bloodline](https://www.aonprd.com/BloodlineDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Orc), gains the Orc subtype and henceforth counts as an Orc.

The [Racial Heritage](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Racial%20Heritage) & [Planar Heritage](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Planar%20Heritage) feats treat your character as if it belonged to a specific race, though you keep your original race in this case as well. The Mythic version of Racial Heritage grants you one of the chosen race's racial traits.

There are also ways to become Undead, for example turning into a Lich or Vampire, though these don't rely on class abilities either: Occult Rituals like [Eternal Apotheosis](https://www.aonprd.com/OccultRituals.aspx?ItemName=Eternal%20Apotheosis) or [Fourth Apotheosis](https://www.aonprd.com/OccultRituals.aspx?ItemName=Fourth%20Apotheosis) provide everyone with the ability to turn into a Lich or Fiend (evil Outsider) respectively. Druids can turn into an undead Siabrae with [Welcome the Blighted Soul](https://www.aonprd.com/OccultRituals.aspx?ItemName=Welcome%20the%20Blighted%20Soul).

Comment: I hadn't thought to add the Monk's ability to become a Outsider, but that is a good example of what I was trying to explain... The Rituals are great for examples of how to change yourself into virtually anything if you want to alter them to change yourself into virtually any other species or creature type.

Comment: [Sanguine Angel](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/s-z/sanguine-angel/) also transforms you into an Outsider[evil, lawful, extraplanar], and sets your native plane to Hell. It's a prestige class, but has a rather narrow intended playstyle.